# Jquery link redirect

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net, webforms

I am writing an asp.net c# webforms website

I am trying to write some jquery to achieve the following:

When the below link is clicked

`<a title="Relevance" href="www.url.com/search/1/3/5/1/4/0">my link</a>`

I would like to have some jquery that takes the href and replaces the last number in this case 0 altho we can change the 0 for any replacable string it this makes it easier. with the value of an  once this has been done we would like to then redirect the user to the new URL.

Is this easily achievable in jquery? Can any one point me in the direction of a tutorial to achieve anything similar to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change the trailing 0 to any replaceable string, can you also change it to `String.Empty`? That way, instead some kind of search-and-replace you can just append a value onto the URL, which is much simpler.

So you'd start with:

```
<a class="search-link" title="Relevance" href="www.url.com/search/1/3/5/1/4/">my link</a>
```

And kind of like what Tejs said but simpler:

```
$('a.search-link').click(function()
{
     var currentUrl = this.href;             
     currentUrl += 'myNewValue';        
     window.location.href = currentUrl;
});
```

Comment: It is something that is possible and would make life very easy, i guess the problem occurs as if javascript is disabled there is no default a thinking about it i could just default it on page load.

Comment: Incase this helps anyone in the future I also found that as well as the above code I also needed to prefent the default action within the method.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do something like this (not checked for accuracy, but the algorithm should be sound):

```
$('#myLink').click(function()
{
     var currentUrl = this.href;

     var items = currentUrl.split('/');
     items[items.length - 1] = 'myNewValue';


     window.location.href = items.join('/');
});
```

Effectively, split by the slash, then replace the last element, rejoin the string together, and set the window's href to your new location.

Comment: I had roughly the same thing but I'm deleting and +1'ing this for the nice touch of the redirect at the end!

Answer (score 0):

You can always do this: http://jsfiddle.net/9Kvfh/

```
$(function()
{
    $('.replaceLastNumber').each(function()
    {
        $(this).click(function(ev)
        {
            ev.preventDefault();

            var ahref = $(this).attr('href');
            var Length = ahref.length;

            if (ahref.slice(Length - 1, Length) == '/') //Remove trailing slash
                ahref = ahref.slice(0, Length - 2);
            else
                ahref = ahref.slice(0, Length - 1);
            ahref += "SomeNewValue";

            window.location.href = ahref;
        });
    });
});
```

I feel like it could be done better a different way (this system has many failure points, from you changing your php code, to them having js off).

Answer (score 0):

A fairly simple method would be to find the final slash, trim its value and replace it with what you want:

html:

```
<a title="Relevance" id="link1" href="http://www.url.com/search/1/3/5/1/4/0">my link</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#link1').click(function(){

    // get the url
    var url = this.href;

    // get the length of the final slash value
    var finalSlashLength = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).length;

    // trim the final value off
    var newUrl = url.substring(0, url.length - finalSlashLength);

    // add the new value
    newUrl += 'some new value';

    // redirect to the new URL
    window.location.href = newUrl;     
});
```

Working sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/QRpYC/2/

**EDIT:**

Since you mention in the comments the markup is generated dynamically - you can easily find the links based on other options. The first thing I'd look for is do they sit in a common container, such as a div, etc? Look for the parent with a name, class or ID attribute and use this as a selector.

For example if the markup is like this:

```
<div id="searchLinks">
    <a title="Relevance" href="http://www.url.com/search/1/3/5/1/4/0">my link</a>
    <a title="SomeLink" href="http://www.url.com/search/1/3/5/1/4/1">my link</a>
</div>
```

Then you can select them using:

```
$('div#searchLinks > a').click(function(){....});
```

Comment: Thanks to all of the posts above.

One thing that I forgot to mention is that The links are dynamically generated as a result I am unable to assign them a unique id so referencing them by #linkid causes me issues. I am also unable to have this occur for all a tags as there are items on the page that do not require this. 

Am i going to be better of just creating a simple java script function and using the onClick of the link? or is there a similar method to use jquery as i would like to try and keep consistancy wiht the scripting language in use

Comment: Prib, can you use CSS classes for these special links? Take a look at my answer for an example using the class "search-link"

Comment: I can that looks exactly like what i want I will give it ago now